# How we get unmatched values from tables in mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a problem in fetching data from mysql database tables.
I have two tables like table-1 and table-2 in below figure. How to get data from table-2 when pilotid is not equal to 1 in table-1.

[image: Mysql database tables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understand correctly, but this returns all rows of table-1, that do not have a matching entry in table-2. You can find the respective documentation of `NOT EXISTS` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table-1 t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM table-2 t2 WHERE t1.`Venueid` = t2.`Venueid` )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.venueid, a.name 
from table2 a, table-1 b 
where b.pilotid <> 1 and b.venueid = a.venueid;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT        Table_2.*
    FROM      Table_2
    LEFT JOIN Table_1
        ON    Table_2.Venueid = Table_1.Venueid
    WHERE     Table_1.Venueid != 1
        OR    Table_1.Venueid NOT IN(1, 13, 15);
```

Comment: where do you get the `13`, and `15` values from?

Comment: 13 & 15 were examples for when the case dictates that you want exclude more than one ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "select Venueid from Table1 where pilotid <> 1";
$data = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
 $ids[] = $row['Venueid'];
}
$sql2 = "select * from Table2 where venueid IN(".implode(',', $ids).")";
$data2 = mysql_query(sql2);

//$data2 contains the result-set resource;
```

Comment: This is a very bad practice. SQL was designed to handle these kinds of filtering and sorting needs. It's faster than PHP at doing any of these things and it can guarantee transactional safety and data integrity while PHP implementations need walk the extra mile for that.